# FileNotFoundException at codechef using Java Code

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

I had tried several times running programs in Codechef environment, with the same run-time error:

*Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/lowJwm/entradaLab6.xml (No such file or directory)*

How do I do to my java programs to read files (.xml, .txt, .csv) at codechef environment?

I already tried to put the file to be read in several different directories, but nothing worked.

Comment: Why dealing with files on Codechef is required? Isn't this [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)?

Comment: If you are providing a file path that is in your local PC/Laptop then it will only run in your local PC. Codechef cannot access that path since that path does not exist in codechef environment rather in your local PC. naturally FileNotFoundException will occur.